# Memory game (second cart doesnt show)

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm programming Memory game in java. Everything works fine but when i want to turn second card it do nothing. I need to see this card at least for one second but sleep command doesnt work. Does anyone know what to do?

```
package MatchJavaFX;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class TheHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

int player1Score;
int player2Score;
boolean player1 = true;
ObservableList<Node> selectedPane_1_Label;
ObservableList<Node> selectedPane_2_Label;
Pane selectedPane1;
Pane selectedPane2;
int count = 0;

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

    Node selected = (Node) t.getTarget();
    if (selected instanceof Pane) {
        count++;
        if (count %2==1) { //prvni klik
            selectedPane1 = (Pane) selected; // vybere policko
            selectedPane_1_Label = selectedPane1.getChildren(); //vezme info z policka
            if (selectedPane_1_Label.get(0) instanceof Label)
            {
                ((Label) selectedPane_1_Label.get(0)).setVisible(true); // "otoci kartu"
            }
        } else if (count %2== 0) { // druhy klik
            selectedPane2 = (Pane) selected; // vybere policko
            selectedPane_2_Label = selectedPane2.getChildren(); //vezme info z policka
            if (selectedPane_2_Label.get(0) instanceof Label)
            {
                    ((Label) selectedPane_2_Label.get(0)).setVisible(true); // melo by otocit druhou kartu ?? --- THIS DOESNT WORK ?
            }
            // pokud se policka rovnaji tak :
            if (((Label) selectedPane_1_Label.get(0)).getId().equals(((Label) selectedPane_2_Label.get(0)).getId())) {
                ((Label) selectedPane_1_Label.get(0)).setVisible(true); // ponecha viditelnou kartu
                ((Label) selectedPane_2_Label.get(0)).setVisible(true); // ponecha viditelnou kartu

                if (player1) { // hraje hrac 1
                    player1Score++; // ricteni k jeho skore (pokud otoci dve stejne karty)
                    player1 = false;
                    MainJavaFX.score.setText("HRAC1 = " + player1Score + "  -  HRAC2 = " + player2Score);
                    MainJavaFX.status.setText("Hraje HRAC2:"); // change to player 2
                    checkWinner(); // konec hry ?
                } else { // else hraje hrac 1
                    player2Score++; // pricteni k jeho skore (pokud otoci dve stejne karty)
                    player1 = true;
                    MainJavaFX.score.setText("HRAC1 = " + player1Score + "  -  HRAC2 = " + player2Score);
                    MainJavaFX.status.setText("Hraje HRAC1:"); // change to player 1
                    checkWinner();// konec hry ?
                }
            } else { // else pokud se ty 2 karty nerovnaji
                /*try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/
                ((Label) selectedPane_1_Label.get(0)).setVisible(false); // schova kartu
                ((Label) selectedPane_2_Label.get(0)).setVisible(false);


                if (player1) { // hraje hrac 1
                    player1 = false;
                    MainJavaFX.status.setText("Hraje HRAC2:"); // prepne na hrace 2
                    checkWinner(); // konec hry ?
                } else { // hrac 2 hraje
                    player1 = true;
                    MainJavaFX.status.setText("Hraje HRAC1:"); // prepne na hrace 1
                    checkWinner(); //konec hry ?
                }
            }


            MainJavaFX.status.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

    }
}

void checkWinner() { // pokud hra skonci
    if (player1Score + player2Score == MainJavaFX.gridSize * 2) { // if score = number of labels
        if (player1Score > player2Score) // porovnani skore
        {
            MainJavaFX.status.setText("Vyhral HRAC1");
        } else if (player1Score < player2Score) // porovnani skore
        {
            MainJavaFX.status.setText("Vyhral HRAC2");
        } else if (player1Score == player2Score) // stejne skore
        {
            MainJavaFX.status.setText("Nerozhodne");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is not Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I don't understand. What more I need to do ?

Comment: And your Code comments are useless. Because they are not in English so its harder to read your code.

Comment: You need to create a [MCVE]. It should be both *minimal* (i.e. just enough to show the problem, but no more) and *complete* (which means we should be able to compile it and run it as it stands).

Comment: Thanks for geting me know. I try to set question once again but better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe changing

```
    try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

to this

```
Timeline hideAfter1sec = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), sec->{
                ((Label) selectedPane_1.Label.get(0)).setVisible(false);
                ((Label) selectedPane_2.Label.get(0)).setVisible(false);
            })
    );
    hideAfter1sec.playFromStart();
```

could help.

Since I wasn't quite sure of what you're doing at some points, I mopped up something that possibly does something similar to what you were trying to accomplish.

So maybe you could check on it, and possibly get some ideas, of another way of doing what you're (possibly) doing:

[link](https://github.com/csumpakabra/WasshupSO/blob/master/src/wasshupso/WasshupSO.java)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works problem solved.